# preg_replace неверно работает для UTF-8 строк

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать обрезку окончаний, но к сожалению не работает. Проблема в кодировке UTF-8, подскажите, как решить проблему? Вместо обрезанного слова на выходе получаю слово и на конце кракозябра.

```
$znach = 'тестовое';
$znach = trim($znach); 

    $reg = "/\.|,|!|\?/i"; 
    $znach = preg_replace($reg,'',$znach); 
    $reg = "/[ый|ой|ая|ое|ые|ому|а|о|у|е|ого|ему|и|ство|ых|ох|ия|ий|ь|я|он|ют|ат]$/";

    $znach = preg_replace($reg,'',$znach);
```

Comment: добавьте `/../iu`, если дело в кодировке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Флаг `u` в помощь.

```
/(ый|ой|ая|ое|ые|ому|а|о|у|е|ого|ему|и|ство|ых|ох|ия|ий|ь|я|он|ют|ат)$/u
```

php изначально же ж не держит unicode, если ему не сказать иначе.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
u (PCRE_UTF8)

И да, по смыслу вместо диапазона нужны альтернативы — скобки не квадратные, а круглые.

Comment: Шикарно вроде сработало!! )) Спасибо!!